# jQuery delay doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, delay

I have the following jQuery code

```
$("#dropdown").hover(function() { 
        $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo('fast',1);
        $("#options").stop(true,true).slideDown();
    }, function() { 
        $(this).delay(1000).stop(true,true).fadeTo('fast',0.1);
        $("#options").delay(1000).stop(true,true).slideUp();
    }
);
```

What I expect to happen is when the mouse leaves `#dropdown` it will wait 1 second before continuing.  This is not happening.

What I am trying to achieve, in case there is a better way, is to leave the drop down menu visible for a second or two after moving your mouse and I would also like to prevent the events from happening again to prevent artifacts and "funnies" if you were to move the mouse over and out from the div very quickly

Comment: One note: durations should be given in milliseconds to routines like `fadeTo`

Comment: @Pointy: 1 and 0.1 are opacity values

Comment: Also @Chris: thanks for noting what your actual goal is. I wish everybody would do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is .stop().  If you take that out it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/LZ8yt/

Answer (score 1):

Your calls to `stop` aren't placed on the animation queue - they run immediately.  I'm not sure whether you really need them in the "hover out" routine.

*edit* removed dumbness

Answer (score 0):

You can always go lo-tech with setTimeout.

```
var dropDownElement = $(this);
setTimeout(function()
{
    dropDownElement.fadeTo('fast', 0.1);
    // Other Code
}, 1000);
```